# Screen goes blank when VLC is playing a video

Tags: video

During playback of a video file (on the HDD) the screen attempts to go blank.  If I move the mouse the blank screen disappears and I am able to see the video again.
I have checked the settings; Tools>Preferences>All (to select the Advanced Menu)>Video and placed a check mark (ticked) Turn off Screensaver (which, by the way, was already selected) but this seems to have no effect.  The screen is still trying to go blank during video playback.
I do not believe that this is an issue with VLC at this point.  However, I have been wrong B-4.
Any help with this matter is greatly appreciated.

My OS is Linux Ubuntu Ultimate Edition 3.2

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set your screensaver to automatically turn on after x minutes, that explains it. Try going into your screensaver settings, disable your screensaver and then re-test.

I would tell you where those settings were, but i have no idea regarding UE 3.2, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

It may be problem with your VLC. Reinstall VLC player.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you were to explain how to do that.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with VLC